# Is there a direct way to send container logs to azure log analytics workspace from iot edge device?

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-iot-hub

I am looking for a solution to send the application logs generated on iot edge devices to an azure log analytics workspace.

I have tried using the Microsoft Monitoring agent using which I was able to send logs generated by running docker containers. However, on an edge device, we are using the moby engine instead of the docker daemon because of which monitoring agent is not collecting the log records(followed this set up to run with docker - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/containers#install-and-configure-windows-container-hosts). Moreover, since I am running my edge environment on windows, I didn't find any container image of monitoring agent targeted for windows.(present for Linux https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/oms/)

I am looking for a completely automated way of streaming application logs , generated on the edge device, to azure log analytics workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way as of today (might be worth checking with team on Github, as they might have this on the roadmap).

However, you can build your own solution using the new [log-pull feature](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/master/doc/built-in-logs-pull.md):

- Write a small time-triggered Azure Function that pulls the logs every few minutes for the containers you are interested in (or all containers). The logs will be written to a storage account
- A second blob-triggered Function picks up the uploaded logs and sends them into Log Analytics.

**//Edit: Very new feature (still in Release Candidate for Edge 1.0.9): https://github.com/veyalla/ehm This might be exactly what you are looking for**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does the log pull feature pick up the logs from docker stderr/stdout stream or is it expected to use additional log drivers?

Comment: It picks up the same logs as `iotedge logs MyModule` produces

Comment: @harikat see my edit. There is a new feature which might be very interesting for you

Comment: Thanks for the edit . That definitely seems promising

Comment: I have tried the log pull feature , by trying to invoke as a direct method from azure portal , I get the error {"status":400,"payload":{"message":"Command 'UploadLogs' not found. The supported commands are - ping"}}. Its same when I try it through cloud shell . Are there any additional constraints around this?(I have checked the environment variables and they are set right)

Comment: are you on the latest version? did you send the command against the edgeAgent? (not edgeHub)

Comment: Oh I was using an old image of the Edge Agent , corrected it and retrying.

Comment: I understand that the features you have directed me to are in the experimental stage. Is there any recommended/preview feature that may be more production fit?

Comment: I think the link points to an outdated repo. Shouldn't it be this one? https://github.com/veyalla/logspout-loganalytics

Comment: @ddegasperi no, your link points to something else (and it is even older)