# How to use application insights for capturing iot edge device logs?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-iot-edge, appinsights

I am trying to understand the use of application insights for capturing the module logs and considering appinsights as a potential option.

I am keen on understanding how would the appinsights work considering there would be multiple devices each running the same modules where modules are configured to send log data to appinsights. The type of data I want to capture are container logs which are currently being sent to stderr/stdout streams.I am expecting this to work on windows devices , hence the logspout project may not be useful here (https://github.com/veyalla/logspout-loganalytics) but i want to do something similar.

I am trying to figure out a design where module logs from multiple edge devices can be captured using appinsights. It would be immensely useful for me to know if appinisghts is really suited for the problem I am trying to solve and how can it be used for multiple devices.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58180111/1537195

Comment: Oh wait, you were the one that asked the other thread :D So what's still open for you? Or what is different with this question?

Comment: Well, I tried that feature and it's useful definitely. However, I am kind of hesitant to use it as it is still an experimental feature, so, I started looking at app insights as another option. I think app insights may do the work but was confused as to how it can be used in a production scenario considering multiple edge devices. I am also not sure if app insights indeed may be a better approach as it seems like to be more useful with web apps.

Comment: well sure you can use app insights. But in this case you need to build the entire logic yourself how to get the logs into there. Either you use the AppInsights SDK directly in your modules code. But then they always need to be online to send up the logs. Or you implement some logic in the cloud that calls the pull-logs direct method on the EdgeAgent and puts them from there into AppInsights. So even though this new feature is still experimental, I would probably rather go with it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a good/secure solution for Windows containers that does a continuous push of module logs to log analytics.

Since the built-in log pull via edgeAgent is experimental, we might change the API or make some modifications but we're unlikely to pull the feature entirely without an equivalent alternative.